# Let $(\Omega , {\mathcal A}, P)$, with random variable $X$ and another function $Y:\Omega \rightarrow R$, does $P(X=Y)=1$ guarantee Y to be a R.V?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega , {\mathcal A}, P)$, with random variable $X$ and another function $Y:\Omega \rightarrow R$, does $P(X=Y)=1$ or similarly $P(X \leq Y)=1$ guarantee Y to be a R.V?

MY thought is that $P(X(\omega) = Y(\omega))=1$.  So X and Y should be equivalent but I am not sure this guarantee $Y$ being measurable w.r.p.t ${\mathcal A}$

I haven't encounter a non-measurable function before so I cannot think of any example of Y being non-measurable.

Comment: This is one reason someone might prefer to work in a [complete measure space](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_measure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Counter-example: Let $\Omega=[0,1]$, $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{B}([0,1])$,
and $P=\delta_{0}$. That is, $P(A)=\begin{cases}
0, & \mbox{if }0\notin A\\
1, & \mbox{if }0\in A
\end{cases}.$Then $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ is a probability space. Let $X=10$
(i.e., a constant random variable). Choose any non-measurable set
$A\subseteq[0,1]$ such that $0\notin A$. Such $A$ exists. Define
$Y:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $Y(\omega)=\begin{cases}
10, & \mbox{if }\omega=0\\
2, & \mbox{if }\omega\in A\\
-3, & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{cases},$ then $[X=Y]=\{0\}$. Hence, $P\left([X=Y]\right)=P(\{0\})=1$. On
the other hand, if $Y$ is a random variable (i.e, $Y$ is measurable),
then $Y^{-1}(\{2\})\in\mathcal{A}$. However, $Y^{-1}(\{2\})=A\notin\mathcal{A}$.